# Flutter project size - is it normal to have huge iOS and Build folders?

Tags: android, ios, git, flutter

I have a Flutter project where the app release files themselves (.ipa and .apk) are only around 10MB each. However, the build folder is 985MB and the iOS folder is 435MB. Bearing in mind I am using a local GIT repository, is this normal? It just seemed very large compared to the app itself.

Comment: Never used flutter before, but that seems very weird

Comment: Yeah it's perfectly normal. As I can see all of my build folders are close to 1GB.

Comment: Yes.  Any doubt, just `flutter clean` and rebuild.  If it ends up same size, then that was right. :)

Comment: Just remember to add proper .gitignore file. Here is one for flutter https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/.gitignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it's ok, and one thing you did not notice in flutter is when you run debugging and install the debug apk on your phone the size of the app is greater than 100 or 150 MB.

But there is no problem just push your code on a git repository and it will be between 10 to 30 MB and if you use flutter clean then it should be 5 to 10 MB.